# Page break in print in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I wanted to use CSS Grid in one of my projects. I have a print functionality as well.

I am having some trouble with my page-breaks. If I give a `page-break-inside: avoid` for a `class`, if that class cannot be accommodated on the same page, it moves to the next page. However, if it is bigger than the page itself. It gets truncated (Footer class in image).

This is how my HTML file looks like -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sample For New CSS Grid Layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      A Header
    </div>
    <div class="name">
      <img class="name-child name-image" src="default_user.png"></img>
      <div class="name-child">LastName1234, FirstName1234</div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <p>
      Pellentesque sed diam erat. Etiam porttitor luctus orci eu mattis.
      Morbi et magna ut leo placerat vestibulum. Donec at enim at nisl convallis congue.
      Morbi fringilla dui leo, quis laoreet ligula cursus sit amet.
      Nunc pharetra pretium libero, eget bibendum odio volutpat eget.
      Ut vel porttitor nisi. Phasellus in pulvinar sapien, vel iaculis turpis.
      Duis et neque ut tortor ornare lacinia faucibus ac magna.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content-title">
      <div class="main-content-title-text">Summary 2018</div>
      <button class="main-content-title-button">Print</button>
      <button class="main-content-title-button">Questions</button>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Duis eget mi nec lorem iaculis scelerisque. Suspendisse potenti.
      Praesent finibus, elit ut tempus consectetur, velit metus fermentum neque,
      blandit facilisis nunc tortor elementum metus. Ut facilisis posuere turpis in 
      feugiat. Ut ullamcorper urna ut euismod malesuada. Ut est sapien, 
      lacinia non egestas et, scelerisque id nunc. Vivamus ac nunc sit amet leo sagittis
      dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
      per inceptos himenaeos.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-title">Available online at www.abc.xyz</div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Duis eget mi nec lorem iaculis scelerisque. Suspendisse potenti.
      Praesent finibus, elit ut tempus consectetur, velit metus fermentum neque,
      blandit facilisis nunc tortor elementum metus. Ut facilisis posuere turpis in 
      feugiat. Ut ullamcorper urna ut euismod malesuada. Ut est sapien, 
      lacinia non egestas et, scelerisque id nunc. Vivamus ac nunc sit amet leo sagittis
      dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
      per inceptos himenaeos.
      </p>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Duis eget mi nec lorem iaculis scelerisque. Suspendisse potenti.
      Praesent finibus, elit ut tempus consectetur, velit metus fermentum neque,
      blandit facilisis nunc tortor elementum metus. Ut facilisis posuere turpis in 
      feugiat. Ut ullamcorper urna ut euismod malesuada. Ut est sapien, 
      lacinia non egestas et, scelerisque id nunc. Vivamus ac nunc sit amet leo sagittis
      dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
      per inceptos himenaeos.
      </p>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Duis eget mi nec lorem iaculis scelerisque. Suspendisse potenti.
      Praesent finibus, elit ut tempus consectetur, velit metus fermentum neque,
      blandit facilisis nunc tortor elementum metus. Ut facilisis posuere turpis in 
      feugiat. Ut ullamcorper urna ut euismod malesuada. Ut est sapien, 
      lacinia non egestas et, scelerisque id nunc. Vivamus ac nunc sit amet leo sagittis
      dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
      per inceptos himenaeos.
      </p>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Duis eget mi nec lorem iaculis scelerisque. Suspendisse potenti.
      Praesent finibus, elit ut tempus consectetur, velit metus fermentum neque,
      blandit facilisis nunc tortor elementum metus. Ut facilisis posuere turpis in 
      feugiat. Ut ullamcorper urna ut euismod malesuada. Ut est sapien, 
      lacinia non egestas et, scelerisque id nunc. Vivamus ac nunc sit amet leo sagittis
      dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
      per inceptos himenaeos.
      </p>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Duis eget mi nec lorem iaculis scelerisque. Suspendisse potenti.
      Praesent finibus, elit ut tempus consectetur, velit metus fermentum neque,
      blandit facilisis nunc tortor elementum metus. Ut facilisis posuere turpis in 
      feugiat. Ut ullamcorper urna ut euismod malesuada. Ut est sapien, 
      lacinia non egestas et, scelerisque id nunc. Vivamus ac nunc sit amet leo sagittis
      dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
      per inceptos himenaeos.
      </p>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Duis eget mi nec lorem iaculis scelerisque. Suspendisse potenti.
      Praesent finibus, elit ut tempus consectetur, velit metus fermentum neque,
      blandit facilisis nunc tortor elementum metus. Ut facilisis posuere turpis in 
      feugiat. Ut ullamcorper urna ut euismod malesuada. Ut est sapien, 
      lacinia non egestas et, scelerisque id nunc. Vivamus ac nunc sit amet leo sagittis
      dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
      per inceptos himenaeos.
      </p>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Duis eget mi nec lorem iaculis scelerisque. Suspendisse potenti.
      Praesent finibus, elit ut tempus consectetur, velit metus fermentum neque,
      blandit facilisis nunc tortor elementum metus. Ut facilisis posuere turpis in 
      feugiat. Ut ullamcorper urna ut euismod malesuada. Ut est sapien, 
      lacinia non egestas et, scelerisque id nunc. Vivamus ac nunc sit amet leo sagittis
      dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
      per inceptos himenaeos.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS file looks like this -

```
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1800px;
}

.wrapper > div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}

.wrapper .main-content-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.wrapper .main-content-title-text {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.wrapper .name {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrapper .name > :first-child {
  margin-left: 0px !important;
}

.wrapper .name .name-child {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 60px 60px 60px auto auto 30px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper > :nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.wrapper .header {
  grid-column: 1 / 13;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.wrapper .name {
  grid-column: 1 / 13;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.wrapper .menu {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / -1;
}

.wrapper .main-content-title {
  grid-column: 3 / 9;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}

.wrapper .main-content {
  grid-column: 3 / 9;
  grid-row: 4 / -1;
}

.wrapper .footer-title {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper .footer {
  grid-column: 9 / 13;
  grid-row: 3 / -1;
}

@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  .wrapper .menu {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 3 / -1;
  }

  .wrapper .main-content-title {
    grid-column: 3 / 9;
    grid-row: 3;
  }

  .wrapper .main-content {
    grid-column: 3 / 9;
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
  }

  .wrapper .footer {
    grid-column: 3 / 9;
    grid-row: 5 / -1;
  }
}

/*@media print {
  .wrapper {
    max-width: 1800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .wrapper .menu {
    display: none;
  }

  .main-content-title-button {
    display: none;
  }

  .footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .footer::before {
    content: "Available online at www.abc.xyz";
  }
}*/
@media print {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-rows: 60px 60px auto 30px auto
  }

  .wrapper .main-content-title {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
  }

  .wrapper .name {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
  }

  .wrapper .main-content {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
  }

  .wrapper .footer-title {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
  }

  .wrapper .footer {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 5 / 6;
  }

  /*.wrapper .footer::before {
    content: "Available online at www.abc.xyz";
  }*/

  .wrapper > :nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
  }

  .wrapper .header {
    display: none;
  }

  .wrapper .name .name-image {
    display: none;
  }

  .wrapper .main-content-title .main-content-title-button {
    display: none;
  }

  .wrapper .menu {
    display: none;
  }

  .wrapper .footer-title {
    display: unset !important;
  }

  .wrapper .footer-title {
    page-break-after: always;
  }

  .wrapper .footer {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }


}
```

The page looks like this - 
[image: In Firefox]

The print preview looks like this -
[image: Page 1 in Firefox print preview]
[image: Page 2 in Firefox print preview]

I had some questions (for print) -

1. If the `footer` is in page2, and its content is bigger than the a single page in print, how do I make it span over page2 and page3.
2. If the `main-content` itself is bigger and part of it goes to page2 and `footer` is small enough to fit on the same page, how do I do that.